# Complex MySQL query, how to select all ingredients and get the quantity needed for orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query that I want to list out the ingredients on hand, and also the amount of the ingredients needed for any orders outstanding. The query works fine if the ingredient is being used in an order, but if it has not been used in an order yet it will not show the ingredient in the query.

Is there a way to structure this query so that it shows all ingredients and the quantity on hand, as well as the amount needed for any outstanding orders?

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance. (*0.00220462 converts grams to pounds)

```
SELECT products.units, (orders_items.quantity - orders_items.quantity_baked) AS                                
num_loaved_needed, inventory.title, inventory.id, ROUND(inventory.quantity * 0.00220462,2)  
as pounds,
ROUND(SUM( (dough_recipes.grams / doughs.yield) * products.weight * (orders_items.quantity 
 - orders_items.quantity_baked) * 0.00220462 ),2) AS amount_needed_for_all_current_orders
          FROM orders_items 
          LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = orders_items.product_id
          LEFT JOIN doughs ON doughs.id = products.dough_id
          LEFT JOIN dough_recipes ON dough_recipes.dough_id = products.dough_id
          LEFT JOIN inventory ON inventory.id = dough_recipes.inventory_id
          GROUP BY inventory.id
          ORDER BY title ASC
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Naturally it won't show up if it hasn't been used in an order yet, since the primary table you're selecting from is `orders_items`. Try selecting from the primary table of interest first (e.g. `products`), and then left join additional `order_item` information as needed. You could also keep `orders_items` as your primary select table, and do `RIGHT JOIN` instead of LEFT. See this visual chart of joins and how they behave: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Thanks AgmLauncher. I am going to try to reconstruct the query, also thanks for the Right Join info. Looks like I have some homework. :)